# Can I change the "mini" wireless card in my Dell laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, pci-express, dell-studio

I have a Dell Studio XPS 16 and I would like to replace the built in wireless card.

Is the "mini" card they call it actually a mini pci express card?

If so can I then swap it out with another 3rd party card e.g this one (dont worry about drive issues):

http://www.justop.com/catalog/apple-shop/airport-and-wireless/apple-airport-extreme-802.11n-mini-pci-e-card-ar5bxb72-macbook-mac-pro.html

As background, I found the online service manual here:

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/sxl16/en/sm/minicard.htm#wp1180188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the cards pictured at both links you gave are PCI Express Mini cards.

Comment: please watch your language, including what you say behind the scenes.  Your answer was flagged, and I deleted it because you could have posted your answer as a comment, as a one word answer is not helpful to the OP; you were being smart.